# '$.fn' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

**Problem 1**

Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$.fn' is null or not an object

**Error area:**

```
    $.fn.apply=function(item,content,header){

        $(".featureBox"+item).css('z-index', "1000");
        $("img.featureBox" + item +"top").attr("src",basepath + "box-big-top.jpg");
        $("img.featureBox" + item +"imgcut").attr("src",basepath + "box-big-img"+item+".jpg");
        featureboxcont[item].attr("src",basepath + "box-big-cont.jpg");
        $("img.featureBox" + item +"foot").attr("src",basepath + "box-big-bot2.jpg");
        //$("#NoteModalDialog > #x-dlg-bd > #x-dlg-tab > #acc-ct")

        $("#box"+item+"headtext > .h2div > h2").text(header);
        $("#box"+item+"bottext").css({"top":"181px","width":"205px","font-size":"12px","color":"#ffffff","left":"10"});
        $("#box"+item+"foottext").css({"top":footheight+"px","width":"215px","left":"20"});
        $("#box"+item+"hidden").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#box"+item+"bottext").text(content);
        $("#box"+item+"headtext > .h2div > h2").removeClass("sIFR-replaced");
        callsIFR();
    }
```

**Problem 2**

Error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object

**Error area :**

```
$("#innerWrapper").addClass("js-version");
```

I'm also using protoype.js on page.

Comment: `apply` is already defined for all objects, you probably shouldn't (can't?) change it.  [Read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: @meagar: `apply` is defined for *function* objects, not all objects. jQuery's `fn` is not a function, it's a plain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery and Prototype on the page, `$.fn` will indeed likely be undefined at global scope. The only way to use jQuery and Prototype on the same page is to use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and give it a different symbol than `$`, which Prototype also uses.

Comment: @TJ - first error has gone after implementing your second suggestion of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721815/how-to-be-a-jquery-no-conflict-expert/2721977#2721977 now second error still coming.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your problem is that both prototype and jQuery use the `$` function/variable name. Check out [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on how to set jQuery to not conflict with prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have apply in the declaration?  apply is used to specify this with a method.  typically you would do something like this...

```
var object1 = {X:"stuff"};

var $.fn = function () {
   /* substitute your method here */
   this.X = this.X || "default";
   alert(this.X);
};

$.fn.apply(object1);
```

Comment: my added code is not whole code it's part of code where javascript debugger is highlighting

Comment: @Tim: It's an easy mistake, but I don't think his `apply` has anything to do with the usual `Function#apply`, it's just a convenient term for what he wants to do. jQuery's `$.fn` is not (confusingly!) a function, it's just a reference to the `jQuery.prototype` object.

Answer (score 0):

For the Problem 1 you could solve the conflicts with the prototype.js by just using

```
jQuery.fn.apply = …
```

Then you avoid the conflict between the two libraries.