# How to be a jQuery no.conflict expert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to be a jQuery no.conflict expert?

I mostly face jQuery conflict errors with Prototypes JS. and I'm nota jquery expert.

Can I still solve all conflict problems. how to get expertize to solve conflict issues.

How to know whole code is jquery. what if simple javascript and jquery code mixed in one js file?

What if inside external js code directly begin from

```
       var opbox="";
```

this is source order Which i can't change

**1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2**
I want to remove conflict error from example.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

**3**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Prototype.js"></script>
```

**4**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptaculous.js ></script>
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? The basics are straight-forward: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Incidentally `noConflict` doesn't at all guarantee there will be no conflicts between the frameworks and especially their plugins. For example jQuery adds custom properties to elements it is dealing with; accidentally change, remove or copy those properties by dealing with elements using another framework, and you can terminally confuse it. If you have no other choice but using two frameworks, keep their activities separate from each other as much as you can. But using two frameworks that are as intrusive as jQuery on a single page is to be strenuously avoided.

Comment: jQuery add nothing to elements, it create wrappers. it's only conflict with most libraries is the "$" function alias that is aliasing the jQuery function/object. Plugins codded according to the guidelines should work. The only conflicts i've seen that are hard to work with are event registration ones...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that if you want to use Prototype on the page, `$` must be Prototype's `$`, not jQuery's. Since `$` is just an alias for `jQuery` anyway, jQuery provides the [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function as a means of telling jQuery to return control of `$` back to whatever had it before jQuery was loaded.

That means whenever you might use `$`, you'd use `jQuery` instead, e.g.:

```
$('.foo').hide(); // Hide all elements with class "foo"
```

becomes

```
jQuery('.foo').hide(); // Hide all elements with class "foo"
```

If you're using external scripts, and if they use `$`, you have to modify them. One way is to do a search-and-replace and just change all the (appropriate) `$`'s to `jQuery`.

Another way is to put this just after your script tag including jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

...and then add this at the top of the external script:

```
(function($) {
```

...and this at the bottom of it:

```
})(jQuery);
```

(Yes, this means you have to modify the external scripts.)

What that does is put the entire external script inside a function, within which the `$` symbol is resolved to `jQuery` rather than to Prototype's `$`, because `$` is an argument to that function and so it takes precedence. However, that technique will fail with some scripts. If they expect that their function declarations will happen at global scope (e.g., become properties of the `window` object), then putting the entire script in a function will break that. In those cases, you have to either manually export those functions by assigning them to `window` or use the global search-and-replace option above.

There are examples of this on the jQuery `noConflict` page, although they frequently combine the above with the `ready` function, which might be a bit confusing.

Note bobince's point about conflicts between frameworks not just being limited to the `$` symbol. If you can possibly stick to using just one framework, do that.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - please explain your 2nd method after updating my question.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: So between #1 and #2, you'd put the inline script I show above that calls `noConflict`. Then you'd edit `example.js` to put the lines at the top and bottom of it as described. If you use any script on your own page (separate from `example.js`), be sure to use `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - you mean for external js We just need to wrap external code inside this (function($) { // external code })(jQuery); and no need to replace $ with jquery.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Should work, yeah, because the `$` within their code will resolve to the argument to the anonymous function, rather than to the global.

Comment: @@T.J. Crowder - but what if external code is starting directly from "var opbox="";" ? will ur technique work whatever is written inside external js?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: What you quoted is fine, doesn't matter *unless* they later assume that `opbox` will be a property of the `window` object (which it would be if it were at global scope). Odds are that they don't make that assumption. The only way to know with a particular script is to try it and see.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Is $ sign can used by anyone is simple javascript code also? are simple javascript cod and jquery code can be placed in same external js file?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: We're straying pretty far from the question at this point, but: jQuery isn't a language, it's a library. The language is Javascript. You don't write things "in" jQuery, you write them "in" Javascript *"with"* jQuery. `$` is a valid Javascript identifier (just like `jQuery`, or `foo`). It happens to be used by both Prototype and jQuery, which is one of the places conflicts arise. It has no intrinsic meaning in Javascript (just like `jQuery` or `foo`), it's only because it's used by these libraries that it has any meaning to speak of.

Comment: if jQuery.noConfict() script is issued, $ is released from jquery throughout the page and its child pages.Could u pls tell, if we can make $ to point jquery back.... I tried using $ = jQuery; and $ = jQuery.noConflict(); But both are not working.

Comment: @Raghav: Please post your question as a question, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `$` shortcut, call `jQuery.noConflict()` and use the full length `jQuery()` object when using jQuery functionality.

For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Do some DOM manipulation here
    });
</scipt>
```

Would become:

```
<script>
   jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       // Do some DOM manipulation here
   });
</script>
```

Comment: but how to do in external js?

Comment: Always use the full length jQuery object in your external scripts. That way you only have to add the call to jQuery.noConflict() to your pages.

Comment: what if $(document).ready(function(){ not present at top of external js?

Comment: i wrapped a code inside  as ur 2nd example code but peoblem is not solved.

Comment: If you're going for no conflicts, you shouldn't be using $(document).ready() at the top of external js files. They should be using jQuery(document).ready() instead.

Comment: I added jQuery(document).ready() at the top of external js but it's still not working

Comment: @Justin: I think the issue is that they're not his scripts, they're third-party plug-ins and such which are coded with `$` rather than `jQuery`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - yes code is not mine but jib is to solve other code

Comment: You should be able to use the same `$` to `jQuery` conversion without `$(document).ready()` as discussed on the noConflict page.

Comment: @justkt - You mean in external js file every `$` should be replace by `jQuery`

Comment: Depends on whether you use T. J. Crowder's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
   $(function(){
      alert('code here');
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```